# How can I merge to svg path?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, path

```html
    <svg style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; min-width: 1878px; min-height: 2602px; position: absolute; background-image: none;">
<g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
<g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M 664 821 L 814 821 L 814 1144.63" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke">
</path>
<path d="M 814 1149.88 L 810.5 1142.88 L 814 1144.63 L 817.5 1142.88 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all">
</path>
</g>
<g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
<rect x="544" y="791" width="120" height="60" fill="#ff3333" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all">
</rect>
</g>
<g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
<ellipse cx="814" cy="1191" rx="60" ry="40" fill="#3333ff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all">
</ellipse>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="cursor: move; visibility: visible;">
<rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="15" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></rect>
<rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="transparent" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="3" pointer-events="stroke"></rect>
</g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I have two paths, but one of them represents EndArrow. I want to delete this endArrow and merge it with the other path.

In summary, I want to delete endArrow and combine it with the path that is a straight line above it.
[my screen shoot like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqSvf.jpg)

Comment: According to your comment: you need change the lines dynamically (while arrows will automatically be placed at the end of the path)? If so, you should rather replace your arrow with a [`<marker>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working svg. I deleted the `arrow` path, and changed the coordinates of the `stroke` path from `d="M 664 821 L 814 821 L 814 1144.63"` to `d="M 664 821 L 814 821 L 814 1154"`, so it goes behind the circle.

```
<svg
  style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; min-width: 1878px; min-height: 2602px; position: absolute; background-image: none;">
  <g>
    <g></g>
    <g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;" width="100%" height="100%"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M 664 821 L 814 821 L 814 1154" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10"
          pointer-events="stroke"></path>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
        <rect x="544" y="791" width="120" height="60" fill="#ff3333" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
        <ellipse cx="814" cy="1191" rx="60" ry="40" fill="#3333ff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></ellipse>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="cursor: move; visibility: visible;">
        <rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="15"
          pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></rect>
        <rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="transparent" stroke-opacity="0.3"
          stroke-width="3" pointer-events="stroke"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g></g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: hi @hrystynaKb How did you calculate?
So how did you combine? For example, when the x and y axis are constantly changing, what should I do

Comment: Did nothing to combine, it is combined already. I just added 10 to the stroke 'end coordinate'.Actually it is too much (stroke is long and hides behind the circle). If you want it to stop precisely when circle starts you can calculate how many in coordinates arrow takes and add this amount to the ending point of a stroke. So in the example above ending point of the stroke is `1144.63`  I added 10 to it and rounded. When you will calculate that arrow takes exactly 5.37 (fox example) you need to add this number to the last number of sroke coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Merging both `<path>` elements (line and arrow) is easy:

Just concatenate both `d` attributes like so:

```
<path d="
M 664 821 L 814 821 L 814 1144.63
M 814 1149.88 L 810.5 1142.88 L 814 1144.63 L 817.5 1142.88 Z" 
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" >
</path>
```

There's a catch: You can't apply different fill or stroke properties to your arrow sub-path.

#### Alternative: convert your arrow to a [`<marker>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker) element.

A marker can be applied via attributes/css-properties

`marker-start="url(#marker)"`
`marker-mid="url(#marker)"`
`marker-end="url(#marker)"`

#### Example: merged paths vs. marker

```css
svg{
  width:40em;
  overflow:visible;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.strokeMarker{
  marker-end: url(#markerArrow)
}
```

```html
<p>Marker applied to path</p>

<svg viewBox="500 700 500 600">
  <defs>
    <marker id="markerArrow" viewBox="0 0 7 7" refX="3.5" refY="3.5" markerWidth="7" markerHeight="7" orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <path d="M 7 3.5 l -7 3.5 l 1.7 -3.5 l -1.7 -3.5 z" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)">
        <path d="M 664 821 L 814 821 L 814 1147" fill="none" stroke="black" class="strokeMarker" />
        <path d="M 664 821 L 900 821 L 900 750" fill="none" stroke="black" class="strokeMarker" />
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
        <rect x="544" y="791" width="120" height="60" fill="#ff3333" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all">
        </rect>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
        <ellipse cx="814" cy="1191" rx="60" ry="40" fill="#3333ff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all">
        </ellipse>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="cursor: move; visibility: visible;">
        <rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="15" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></rect>
        <rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="transparent" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="3" pointer-events="stroke"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>


<p>Merged path and arrow</p>
<svg viewBox="500 700 500 600">
  <g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)">
<path d="
M 664 821 L 814 821 L 814 1144.63
M 814 1149.88 L 810.5 1142.88 L 814 1144.63 L 817.5 1142.88 Z" 
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" >
</path>

      </g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
        <rect x="544" y="791" width="120" height="60" fill="#ff3333" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all">
        </rect>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;">
        <ellipse cx="814" cy="1191" rx="60" ry="40" fill="#3333ff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all">
        </ellipse>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="cursor: move; visibility: visible;">
        <rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="15" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></rect>
        <rect x="542" y="789" width="124" height="64" fill="none" stroke="transparent" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="3" pointer-events="stroke"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>



<p>Marker path</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 7 7">
  <path d="M 7 3.5 l -7 3.5 l 1.7 -3.5 l -1.7 -3.5 z" />
</svg>
```